# Assignment to const reference in Visual C++ 2013

Tags: c++, visual-c++, const-reference

In Visual C++ 2013, it is legal to assign a temporary value to a const reference, for example

```
const int& a = 1;
```

In a large software project, I now stumbled upon a single line of code that took around 10 ms to execute:

```
const std::vector<Item>& desc = (hasItems) ? instance->getItems() : std::vector<Item>();
```

*Item* is a struct with around 20 bytes, *instance->getItems()* returns a  *const std::vector< Item>&*.
I did not see any reason why this line should take longer than an instant to execute, so I played around a bit and found out that

```
const std::vector<Item>& desc = std::vector<Item>();
```

also takes 10 ms, while

```
std::vector<Item> items;
const std::vector<Item>& desc = items;
```

is near-instant, i.e. 0.00.. ms, as you would expect.

The thing is, I can reliably reproduce this issue in the existing, complex software project, but in any condensed minimal example, both versions run equally fast. I have tested all of this in a release build with optimizations enabled. Is there any chance that one of these optimization makes this exception to assign a value to a const reference really slow? I would really like to know what causes this behavior. Does anyone have a clue what causes this?

Following up, is there a warning for assigning a value to a const reference that I accidentally disabled? If so, what is its id? It would be handy if the compiler could point out other places in the code where this happens.

Edit: The timings were done with a simple CPU clock right before and right after the code of interest, divided by the clock cycles per second. It's not too accurate, but gives you a general idea of the difference between 10.something and 0.something. And it's not fluctuating in any way, it is perfectly reproducible in this specific example. There is a significant difference in execution time.

Comment: It is legal (and actually quite a useful feature) in C++ to bind a temporary variable to const reference, so there is no warning for that: https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Comment: Side note: that's not an assignment.

Comment: const reference holds temporary object as long as the reference is alive, so it is legal

Comment: The usage of the const reference would not be my first candidate for the performance issue. instance->getItems() could return not a reference but a copy of vector, or being a virtual function could also bring a  little bit of overhead, or just do more than just returning the reference.

Comment: How did you measure that this line takes 10ms?

Comment: @PcAF that refers to vector assignment, because assignment operator of `std::vector` is not called. Only the reference is bound to the instance.

Comment: I believe that the measurement is broken. 10ms is a lot of time and I believe it is related to precision of your timing metod (e.g. GetTickCount precision varies up to 16 ms or more). If you compare generated assembly code you will see exactly what happens, and I believe there will not be much difference

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic I thought that he is trying to say that it's not assignment to reference, but call to copy constructor of `vector` (which is non-sense to me), anyway term `assignment` is unclear in this context.

Comment: @PcAF my understanding was just opposite :) I agree

Comment: @PcAF Because it's an initialisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> const std::vector<Item>& desc =
>       (hasItems) ? instance->getItems() : std::vector<Item>();
> ```

You might not expect it, but this line makes a copy of the vector that the return value of `getItems` refers to.

Formally, the rules of type coercion performed by conditional operator conspire to make it so. Practically speaking, the compiler has no choice: when a reference is bound to a temporary, the compiler needs to generate code to destroy that temporary when the reference eventually goes out of scope - but that would get tricky if the same reference could be bound to a temporary sometimes and to an lvalue other times. It is precisely to avoid this situation that the rules of type coercion are written to ensure that a temporary is created on both branches of the conditional in your case.

Something like this should help:

```
std::vector<Item> blank;
const std::vector<Item>& desc =
      (hasItems) ? instance->getItems() : blank;
```

Or, I suppose, you could design `getItems()` to return a reference to a valid empty vector when it has no items, and not require callers to jump though hoops. Keeping a static always-empty vector variable for that purpose is not unreasonable.

Comment: @Lightness Well, the vector could be very large and/or copying `Item` could be very expensive. But yes, most likely the clock being used simply has a resolution of 10ms.

Comment: @Ig​​​​​​​​​​​​or: Apparently `Item` is "a struct with around 20 bytes" :P although granted that says nothing about what it does on copy construction, and we don't know how many there are :)